# Could not get Postman live collection

Tags: node.js, postman, postman-collection

In the latest version of Postman (v10.22.13), I'm unable to locate the "live collection" feature which I previously used in older versions for nodejs project. Could you please assist me in recreating this functionality or provide guidance on achieving similar results in the current version.
and there is steps in postman documentation which was updated 2024/01/31 but there is no related reference for current version of postman

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.